# puppet and puppetmaster won't start

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have been following a tutorial for installing tomcat using puppet master on CentOs. 
 I have installed from the following repo then ran yum install.

> rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm

and I am getting the following error

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  puppet.service

For puppet master its the same thing. 
 The only difference between this and the tutorial is that I am running CentOS7 ion a VM. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Adam

Comment: That is not an error. That is what happens when you use the wrong service manager on CentOS 7. What happens when you `systemctl status puppet`?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard - much appreciated for getting back to me. Do you know where I can find out what service manager I should be using? I have tried googling but my knowledge is limited I am afraid.
 The output of systemctl status puppet gives me loaded, active but some certificate issues saying can't be found. However not sure if that would affect the module being loaded up?

Comment: So your puppet service is in fact up and running. If you are having some other certificate issues, you may want to delete this question and open a new one with those issues and some descriptive output for the problem. Additionally, you may want to `man systemctl` to get a quick brush up on your new service manager.